# Appropriate time interval to reconnect to websockets

Tags: ios, sockets, meteor, websocket, socket.io

I am using meteorjs on ios. I am able to connect to it using web sockets. Current my application attempts to reconnect with the server every 5 seconds, if I am disconnected. I chose this number randomly, but I am concerned on how this will affect my application.

Is that number too frequent? if yes, what is the appropriate time interval?

Anybody have experience on how this will affect my app in terms of battery life, if my app is constantly trying to reconnect to a web socket?

any help will be greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

5 seconds is alright for reconnection, but could be made more logical!

Now, there are two cases:

1. Temporary error, which might get resolved on first or second
   re-connect
2. Some other network connection, which might take infinite re-connects

For first case, 5 seconds might be too late,  for second case, you might want to re-connect with larger delays.

So, optimal solution will be to start with 0 second and increase the reconnect delay, as it keep failing in loop!

---

Now answer, to your another question:
how this will affect my app in terms of battery life?

It won't more than it is already using while connection is Alive!!